# How can I import sklearn cython apis for my own code?

Tags: python, c++, scikit-learn, cython

In short what I want to do is directly import cython apis from sklearn module. Following is the cython example code.

```
from sklearn.tree._criterion import Entropy
ent = Entropy(1,np.array([2]))
ent.init()
```

It would fail throwing an error called init function doesn't exist. Now init is a cdef function so that might be the issue. If i try to cimport directly Criterion class, it would throw an error stating sklearn.tree._criterion.pxd doesn't exist.

Comment: scikit-learn does have a `_criterion.pxd`, however it doesn't ship with scikit-learn because that cython interface isn't considered a public API. Even if scikit-learn did ship that .pxd file, it doesn't contain prototypes for the `Entropy` class you're trying to use, so that wouldn't even help. If you really want to use this code in your own cython code, you're likely going to need to copy/paste it into your project.